# Shopping cart iphone app

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, paypal

So this app is basically selling several products, users login to their account and start shopping. I am using paypal library to check out. Question is, is there any api that I can update the inventory and update the user purchase history? can asiHttpRequest do the job? something have to do with database? xml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well i dont prefer core data or sql lite in these kind of apps. Use a standard hosting with mysql database support and use PHP webservices to get and post data. On IOS side, use JSon to read the Get and Post. Its really easy to made these kind of apps with PHP Webservices + JSon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use best-buy api to get products and can use coredata to save the particular user cart items.